# What is causing this JMS error connecting to OracleAQ?

Tags: java, queue, jms, spring-jms, oracle-aq

I am getting sporadic errors from a java service that is listening to OracleAQ.

It seems to be happening each night, and I can't be sure what is going on.  Could it really be a database connection problem ?

Or does the "Dequeue failed" suggest that it was connected and something else happened ?

Here is the exception below :

```
[2013-11-04 18:16:16,508] WARN  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MYCOMPANY_INFO_QUEUE' - trying to recover. Cause: JMS-120: Dequeue failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out
oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-120: Dequeue failed
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsError.throwEx(AQjmsError.java:311)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.dequeue(AQjmsConsumer.java:2234)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:1028)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:951)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:929)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receive(AQjmsConsumer.java:781)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:430)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:310)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1096)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1088)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:985)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

[Linked-exception]
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:976)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.dequeue(AQjmsConsumer.java:1732)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:1028)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:951)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receiveFromAQ(AQjmsConsumer.java:929)
       at oracle.jms.AQjmsConsumer.receive(AQjmsConsumer.java:781)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:430)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:310)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1096)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1088)
       at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:985)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

[2013-11-04 18:16:16,569] INFO  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

Comment: Do you have anything between the Java and the database that might drop the connection after a period of time, e.g. a firewall? Unlikely if they're on the same server, but that's come up before as a reason for long-running connections to mysteriously drop.

Answer (score 2):

The jms receive timeout should be configured in seconds (while the db timeout is in milliseconds). So make sure your jms value is less. For example, here is my working spring config:

```
<bean id="xxxJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate102">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="xxxJmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="some_queue"/>

    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10"/><!-- seconds -->

</bean>
```

PS: The special Spring constant RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT value of -1 does not seem to work for this setting. But setting a reasonably short time in seconds should do the trick.

Comment: The 'over zealous neat freak' was a moderator, and your previous answer was [deleted because it was not answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), hitting at least two of those criteria. I realise you don't have [enough reputation to comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) yet, but posting what should be a comment as an answer to get around that is not allowed.

Comment: Well, my post had useful information in it, so I think that deleting it was foolish, regardless of "policy". It turns out that my original post held a clue -- the JMS receive timeout setting is the issue, at least in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at your dequeue options for wait time.

```
import oracle.AQ.AQDequeueOption;
...
AQDequeueOption options = null;
options = new AQDequeueOption();
options.setWaitTime(AQDequeue.WAIT_NONE);
//WAIT_NONE = do not wait if messages are not available
//WAIT_FOREVER = waits "forever"; default value
...
```

The WAIT_FOREVER setting is default and will wait until a message is available on the queue; however this holds the database connection open.
I believe this is the reason why you experience the errors "sporadically"; most of the time messages are being enqueued and running smoothly; and then when messages are not enqueued (each night) your database connection is timing out.